# What is the explicit formula for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I'm trying to use the following  sequence as a scoring system, but couldn't find the explicit formula:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases} 
    a_n= a_{n-1}-200*0.75^{n-2}\\
    a_1=1000
  \end{cases}
 \end{equation}

This generates the following values:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
n & a_n \\ \hline
1 & 1000 \\ \hline
2 & 800 \\ \hline
3 & 650 \\ \hline
4 & 537.5 \\ \hline
\end{array}

The sequence is designed to award a<sub>n</sub> points to the nth ranked player.

What would the explicit formula be, and what is this kind of sequence called?

Comment: Since that is of the form $\Delta a_n=C\times \lambda^n$, it's natural to try something of the form $a_n=A\times \left(\frac 34\right)^n+B$.  Use the values for $a_1, a_2$ to solve for $A,B$.

Comment: Do you know anything about recurrence relations?